# The number of non-negative integral solutions to the equation $4x_1+x_2+x_3=n$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

We know that $x_1+x_2+x_3=n$ has ${{n+2}\choose{2}}$ solutions, but how do we calculate the solutions to an equation such as $4x_1+x_2+x_3=n$?

Please do explain! Thanks!

Comment: Wow this is bright!

Comment: @Lays perhaps you would like to explain to the OP what exactly is your problem with his question? perhaps you even might, by any chance, HELP him with what he doesn't understand???

Comment: @DanielY Lol huh? Check the edit out, you will see what I was referring to.

Answer (score 3):

We want to find the number of non-negative integral solutions to the equation $4x_1+x_2+x_3=n$. We can see that $x_1$ is a multiple of $4$, that is $x_1\in\{0,4,8,...\}$, and $x_2$, $x_3$ have no restrictions, that is $x_2,x_3\in\{0,1,2,3,...\}$.

Consider the generating function $$G(x)=(1+x^4+x^8+\cdots)(1+x+x^2+\cdots)(1+x+x^2+\cdots).$$ 
Where $x_1$ represents the number of apples, $x_2$ represents the number of oranges, and $x_3$ represents the number of bananas. We can rewrite this using the geometric series. So $$G(x)={1\over 1-x^4}\cdot {1\over 1-x}\cdot {1\over 1-x}.$$
Another glance at $G(x)$ and we can see that ${1\over 1-x^4}={1\over 1-x^2}\cdot{1\over 1+x^2}={1\over 1-x}\cdot {1\over 1+x}\cdot {1\over 1+x^2}.$
Thus $$G(x)={1\over (1-x)^3}\cdot {1\over 1+x}\cdot {1\over 1+x^2}.$$

We can use Newton's Binomial Theorem to rewrite $G(x)$ as three different series. The answer we're looking for is the coefficient of $x^n$ in $G(x)$. Computing this by hand is a nightmare. Usually a computer would be used to compute something like this, which is unfortunate.